# Spurious scrollbars in chat GitHub Gist onebox

Tags: bug, chat, design, onebox

Not sure when *this* happened, but can't find any recent complaints about it.

[image]

[The oneboxed gist](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16994677#16994677) has vertical and horizontal scrollbars even though it has no need of them.

I'm using Firefox 31.0 on Fedora 20 / KDE.

---

18 months later, and this is still happening. I see it on Chrome 49.0.2623.87, still on Fedora/KDE, in addition to Firefox.